# How long would it take for all the Bitcoin Key pairs to be calculated?

Tags: security, private-key, public-key

Is this even something one should be worried about?

Comment: This is more fun to calculate for yourself than to ask for the answer.  Why not try it and ask if you get stuck?

Comment: I guess I should take the time it takes to calculate a single key pair and multiply it with the total number of private keys, not the total number of possible addresses (to account for expected(?) collisions). So, totalTime = singleKeyPairTime * 2^256. Right?

Comment: Sure.  Of course, they could be computed in parallel, so if you want the *real* time required to calculate all keys, you should divide by the number of machines being used.

Comment: The closest I have come to answering how long a single ECDSA key generation takes is "some milliseconds". I ran the numbers and even if you run thousands of computers in parallel + assume one computer can calculate tens of thousands of keyGenerations/s, the infinitesimally small percentage of public keys you will find in your lifetime, is simply not worth it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long would it take a large computer to crack a private key?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2847/13866)

Comment: related: [Is Each Bitcoin Address Unique?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8804/5406)

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't worry about it.

`3Blue1Brown` has made a great video explaining how large 256 bit is, [check it out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9JGmA5_unY)